# How to show entire DataGridViewCell when selected (CellEnter event)?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, horizontal-scrolling

I am using VS 2010 and .NET framework 4.0. Is there any way to show entire `DataGridViewCell` (rectangle) when selected (with keys not clicks).
I have a `DataGridView` control with 10 - 12 columns, when not shown cells (physically) are reached with keys, the grid doesn't scrolls horizontally.
I'm using `SelectionMode.FullRowSelect` and `StandardTab = false` properties.

The grid is readonly, the thing is that when user press `Keys.Apps` on `CurrentCell`, a context menu is displayed, but if `CurrentCell` is not shown but focused (with a dotted rectangle) the grid is not scrolled and the menu shouldn't appear.

I've tried setting `Frozen = false` to all code generated columns with no success.

Maybe inside `dataGridView1_CellEnter` event, set current cell (all rectangle, not just data) to be shown completely (if it wasn't before)

(`FirstDisplayedCell` property is not exactly my solution)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried what you described and looks like the problem is present only with using mouse, using the Tab or Arrow key will focus the whole cell for you automatically. So the following solution is to deal with using mouse, allowing user to click on the partially shown cell and make the whole cell displayed after that. We have to handle the `CellClick` event, use the `HorizontalScrollingOffset` property to scroll the horizontal scrollbar programmatically, of course we have to calculate the mount of scrolling ourselves:

```
//CellClick event handler for the dataGridView1
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
  var colRect = dataGridView1.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, false);
  colRect.X = colRect.Right - dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width;
  int offSet = colRect.Right - dataGridView1.Width + 
                               SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
  if (offSet < 0) {
     var rowHeaderWidth = !dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible ? 0 : 
                           dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth;
     offSet = colRect.Left < rowHeaderWidth ? colRect.Left - rowHeaderWidth : 0;
  }
  dataGridView1.HorizontalScrollingOffset += offSet;
}
```

**UPDATE**: for dealing with focusing using keys, you can try handling the `CellEnter` instead, all the code above is still useful:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
  //your problem happens only when ReadOnly is true, so 
  //we just need to handle it when ReadOnly is true
  if(!dataGridView1.ReadOnly) return;
  //the remaining code... 
  //....
}
```

Comment: I just edited the question, what I meant is when cell is focused with keys **not clicks**. i'm sorry for that. Anyway I'm keeping your code, looks interesting and just gave me some ideas for considering, thanks.

Comment: @mck see my update, it's simple that instead of handling the `CellClick`, you can handle the `CellEnter` event, all the code I posted is still useful.

Comment: that problem happens with `ReadOnly` true or false, your code is ok, but what if you go to last cell with Ctrl + right arrow key, `colRect` will be a 0x0 rectangle..

Comment: @mck I'm now not even sure if your problem exists, I've tried it several times and it did exist but somehow after that, it works expectedly by default (don't use any code), the `TAB` and `Arrow` keys simply work as what you want. it's strange enough, looks like it's a bug, not very serious bug in DataGridView. Anyway my code works OK, I don't understand why you think jumping to the last cell will result in `colRect` being an empty Rectangle, note that the `GetColumnDisplayRectangle` works in 2 different ways depending on the second argument (of type `bool`).

Comment: run your code, the last column is not visible due to spacing, press Ctrl + right arrow, `GetColumnDisplayRectangle` returns an empty rectangle, I'm sure of that without testing, if is really a bug, I'm surprised this has not been discussed before, thanks anyway

Comment: @mck don't understand this at all `the last column is not visible due to spacing`

Comment: @mck `I'm sure of that without testing` -> you should not be such professional, why not test? it's just a waste of time? I always try testing everything even it's too obvious that I'm 99.99% sure about the result.

Comment: @mck `GetColumnDisplayRectangle` returns empty Rectangle only when the Column width is Zero, I mentioned that it can accept the second argument a value of `true` or `false`, be sure that you use the value `false` **to return the entire column rectangle**, no matter what it is currently displayed in your dataGridView, there is only one case in which it can be a problem is if your column is not displayed and is located on the left.

Comment: @mck I said it might be a bug because **sometimes I can reproduce your problem, and sometimes I can't**, that means **sometimes I cannot focus the whole cell with TAB key and ARROW keys, but sometimes I can use those keys to focus the whole cell as you expected without using any code**. It's strange indeed. I meant it might be some bug in the DataGridView. You may want to try it several times.

Comment: ok, I'm sorry if I bothered you, I'm not a professional absolutely, just a hobbyist, my fault. Well, **the last column is not visible**, imagine, your dgv has 10 columns, but due to form size we can see only 5 of them, the other ones we can't, and **(important!)** if you previously **set the columns width** to random values, (say 50, 50, 120, 250, etc..), then when press Ctrl + right arrow (go last), the dgv doesn't scrolls, the last cell is reached and selected, but not focused. That is my problem, and that's why we get an empty rectangle.

Comment: when the columns width is set after biniding a list of custom type, is when this happens. Even if we let width columns to default of `AutoGenerateColumns`property, (100 I think), the code goes ok, but, reduce first and second columns to 30-50% its size, and go right with Ctrl + arrow keys, the last one is not displayed, I wanna know why that happens?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this property setting.

```
RowHeadersWidthSizeMode=AutoSizeToDisplayedHeaders;
```

Answer (score 0):

You set a property in grid

`AutoSizeColumnMode` as `AllCells`

It May help you.